# HDR(High Dynamic Range)の画像を非圧縮で格納できる静止画ファイルフォーマット

Tags: 画像, 画像処理

HDR(High Dynamic Range)の画像を非圧縮で格納できる静止画ファイルフォーマットを調べています。

HEIFやJPEG-HDRはHDRを格納できるとおもいますが、これらは非可逆の圧縮のファイルかと思います。
画像処理ソフトなどでは、HDRを非圧縮で保存できるフォーマットがあるのではないかと思っているのですが、そのようなファイルフォーマットは存在するのでしょうか？

情報お持ちでしたら、ご教授ください。

Answer (score 1):

PNGなら48bitカラー（RGB各16bit）を扱えます。
zlibによる圧縮を受けますが、可逆圧縮ですし、必要なら無圧縮も選択できます。

Answer (score 1):

[OpenEXR](https://www.openexr.com/)も圧縮無し・可逆圧縮・不可逆圧縮を選択でき、fp16/fp32/uint32を扱えます。